# Smooth out Plotly Graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Below is my code, generates a random `stock-like datalist`, but the output you can not see the values at all. Is there any way to make the graph output more readable?

```py
import random
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


prices = []
days = [day for day in range(365*12)]
spacing = 10

price = random.uniform(0, 884)

for x in range(365*12):
    prices.append(price-random.uniform(0, 5))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(prices, days)), columns =['Stock Price', 'Days'])

fig = px.line(df, x="Days", y="Stock Price")
fig.show()
```

Example of output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I think [candlestick plots](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/) are popular for "stock-like datasets" where you're more interested in showing increasing or decreasing days. You might literally *smooth* the values by also plotting a [rolling average](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), but otherwise the output shown here seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
import random
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prices = []
days = [day for day in range(365*12)]
spacing = 10

price = random.uniform(0, 884)

for x in range(365*12):
  prices.append(price-random.uniform(0, 100))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(prices, days)), columns =['Stock Price', '_'])

fig = px.line(df.rolling(75).sum()/75, x="_", y="Stock Price")
fig.show()


from functools import reduce

def Average(lst):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, lst) / len(lst)
 
print(round(Average(prices),2))
```

Comment: Judging from this answer, you might be interested in just plotting a scatter plot with a trendline: https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/. You can even completely disable the scatter, but use this to calculate the rolling averages.

Comment: @itscarlayall While that does look like something I could use in the future, I dont really see it fit for the project im currently working on in this question.